# Skip user edit page on first login using fboauth

Tags: social-network

I am using the latest dev version on [FBOAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/fboauth) module on my site. I am using Popup for facebook login.

When the user logs in for the first time using facebook currently the user is being redirected to the account edit page. Is there a way I can skip this test, so that user will be back to the page where he came from. Later on he can go to account edit page and set the password if he wants to. Else he continue using the facebook login only.

Once the account is already connected, I am not facing this issue as the user is rightly directed to the page he came from. The issue is only with the first login using facebook.

Please let me know if there is some setting that I can enable.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the page using `rules` modules and drupal_goto function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the module doesn't have an option for that currently. I have submitted a patch for the same which will add an option on the admin screen to skip the profile edit page on the first login.

You can try the patch here https://www.drupal.org/node/2508838#comment-10041388